# Why my web host has DNS records while my domain is hosted separately and DNS records are there?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, dns-zone

I have my domain registered with **name.com** and the same is my domain host i.e. I use their name servers and all of my DNS records are there only an A record points to my web host while MX records point to Google Apps.

My web host is A2hosting that uses CPANEL. When I opened "Advanced DNS Zone Editor" in CPANEL, I could see default A and CNAME records for my domain. Now the questions are:

1. Do those DNS records have any role while they would never be checked because I'm using nameservers of name.com?
2. Is it safe to delete all those records?
3. How A2hosting binds hosting with my A record?

I would appreciate all answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. No, only those records matter that exist in the servers that your domain's `NS` records point to.
2. Yes it is, but there is no benefit either.
3. A2hosting helps you with that question.